# Wifi and Bluetooth are not working after installation of ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04, dell-vostro

I have dell vostro 3446 version in laptop machine. I have now installed ubuntu 18.04 version. After that bluetooth and wifi has been stopped working.
Even camera also stopped working.
I think it has some missing drivers.
Before than that I had ubuntu 16 LTS version, both bluetooth,wifi was working fine.
Please suggest some better and easy solution for the same.

**Output of some of the basic commands :**

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
Subsystem: Dell RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1028:0662]
Kernel driver in use: r8168
Kernel modules: r8168
08:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] [10de:1140] (rev a1)

$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:9205 Suyin Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2717:ff80
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ lsmod | grep cfg

$ uname -r
4.15.0-34-generic
```

[Attached here output of basic commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCeOL.png)
[No wifi adapter found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWwXT.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; lsmod | grep cfg; uname -r`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks for the help. I have attached here output of commands